# Container wont stay at 100% across browsers

Tags: containers

My container won't stay at 100% height in certain browsers, Firefox 11 OS X being one of them.

I can't post images yet, but here is a link to the website www.iodinemusic.co.uk

Do I need some kind of trick or way of telling different browsers to adjust accordingly?

Comment: Hi, please check out [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Comment: Sorry, new to this, but trying my best,for example, how did the kind gent Pierreten manage to get my iodinecss.css? I am also at work and my website on Dreamweaver resides at home, but I thought I'd get the ball rolling.Thanks for pointing this out though Pekka.

Comment: Your CSS file is linked in your HTML document's "view source" view. One can find and download it from there, that's normal.

Comment: Im aware of View Source, just didn't realise you could extract the css?

Comment: you can extract everything about a web site - otherwise the browser wouldn't be able to know how to display it!

Comment: hey why do i have a negative 2 for my post?

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: table`  to the .container class.

It's line 12 of [iodinecss.css](http://www.iodinemusic.co.uk/iodinecss.css)

Comment: So the first rule in .container. Just literally putting display: table?.